# Advertisement flag non-connectable for BLE

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am building a project that involves Bluetooth Low Energy (core BLE). I would like to make it so multiple devices can scan and advertise to each other. However, I do not want these devices to actually connect.

I know I have to change the advertisement flag to nonconncetable. I am confused on where I would implement this change and how I would go about making it nonconnectable.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Best Regards

Comment: It depends on the bluetooth stack you use how the API looks like. Do you mean you want to do this using CoreBluetooth?

Comment: Hi, @Emil I am using BLE within CoreBluetooth. Do you know if there is a specific function I should alter/include to make it so the advertisement flag is set to non-connectable?

Comment: or like how do I make kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 0 ?

Comment: Hi @NeelMehta , Have you achieved this scenario? If yes, kindly help me with the solution for it.